# Show the amount of committed memory per program on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, monitoring, memory-management

I am looking for a program shows how much committed memory a program has on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. Any license or price is fine.

By committed memory I mean whatever contributes to the 42 GB shown in this screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: As far as I remember you should be able to do that in taskmanager itself. Just go to the "Processes" tab and add the column for "Commit size".

Comment: @Robert Thanks, the column for "Commit size" seems inaccurate: https://superuser.com/a/1680921/116475

Comment: The use Powershell. One of these should be the correct value: `Get-Process | Sort PagedMemorySize64 | Select Name, PagedMemorySize64, PeakPagedMemorySize64`